# SharePoint REST API filter of string with space

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, core-api

I have a list with columns `FirstName` and `LastName`. Using API query, I am able to search for the first name or the last name. i.e.:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$filter=substringof(%27jo%27,Title)and substringof(%27bl%27,LastName)&$select=Title
```

But i have a requirement where the search text is "Joe Bloggs" and it should search the firstname and lastname for this full name.

Is it possible to filter the list using the full name?

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchtext = //get search text from query results or textbox
var FirstNameSearch = searchtext.split(" ")[0];
var LastNameSearch = searchtext.split(" ")[1];

"_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + FirstNameSearch + "' or LastName eq '" + LastNameSearch+ "'&$select=Title";
```

You can probably build out the logic to search again if there are no results for "no results for  , searching for users with firstname of  or lastname of " or something similar.